# Gives exception "java.lang.NullPointerException" while execute two test case parallely

Tags: java, testng, eclipse-mars

// This is my XML code... when i execute (InvalidLogin method) in "Login with valid data" test suite it works successfully but when i try to execute (InvalidLogin method)code in different test suite (ex.Login with Invalid Data) it generates error

```
 <suite name="Test Login" verbose="2" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">

<test name="Login with valid data" >
<parameter name="UserName" value="priyanka"></parameter>
<parameter name="Password" value="vrs~123"></parameter>

<!-- <parameter name="UserNam" value="Chetna12345"></parameter>
<parameter name="Passwor" value="Chetna12345"></parameter> -->


<classes>
<class name="Login_Test">
<methods>
    <include name="openBrowser"></include>
      <include name="SuccessfulLogin"></include>
       <!--  <include name="InvalidLogin"></include> -->

</methods>
</class>
</classes>
</test>
<test name="Login with Invalid Data">
<parameter name="UserNam" value="priyanka"></parameter>
<parameter name="Passwor" value="priyanka"></parameter>    

<groups>
<run>
<include name="TC02"></include>
</run>
</groups>
<classes>
<class name="Login_Test">
<methods>
      <include name="InvalidLogin"></include>
</methods>
</class>
</classes>

</test>
</suite>
```

//This is My method for Successful login and i am doing Logout after login so URL on browser remains open but values for invalid are not getting passed on to Text box...

```
public void SuccessfulLogin(String userName, String passWord) {

    try {

        driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys(userName);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(passWord);

        driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).submit();
```

//Logout Code

```
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.className("dropdown-toggle")).click();

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,    'Account/LogOff')]")).click();


    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
public void InvalidLogin(String Uname,String Pword)
    {   
        driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys(Uname);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(Pword);

        driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).submit();
    }
```

//Out put in Console

```
Login success!!
PASSED: openBrowser
PASSED: SuccessfulLogin("priyanka", "vrs~123")

===============================================
    Login with valid data
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestRunner] Starting executor for test Login with Invalid Data with time out:2147483647 milliseconds.
FAILED: InvalidLogin("priyanka", "priyanka")
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Your second `Login_Test` doesn't include `openBrowser`.

Comment: hello @ElliottFrisch i have updated my code in which i am doing logout after my first test case execution so, when execution starts for "Invalid Login" Login page remains open in browser so, it directly starts to pass invalid data into it..

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Computer, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It should help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

According to XML I suppose you need to add `<include name="openBrowser"></include>` to the second test

Comment: but browser is already open ,, cant i pass the value on that page only?

Comment: you are running tests in parallel, each thread should open separate browser